# Creating a *simple* .htaccess file that can redirect some pages in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having trouble with an .htaccess file redirecting traffic from an old site.  Most of the content has moved. Some static content is staying at the old location, so I want to redirect some of those old paths.  We used to have a CMS that could handle case-insensitivity.  Now it's gone and I want to handle that with the .htaccess file.

I want to use 302's because 301's are harder to test with.  When I'm done, I will switch to 301s.

This is the entire `.htaccess file`

```
#
# Old site redirects
#

# /link1
Redirect 302 /link1 /file.pdf
Redirect 302 /LINK1 /file.pdf

# Everything Else
Redirect 302 / http://www.newsite.com/
```

If the user goes to:

- `http://www.oldsite.com/link1` redirect to `http://www.newsite.com/file.pdf'
- `http://www.oldsite.com/LINK1` redirect to `http://www.newsite.com/file.pdf'
- `http://www.oldsite.com/lINk1` redirect to `http://www.newsite.com/file.pdf'
- `http://www.oldsite.com/news` redirect to `http://www.newsite.com/news'
- `http://www.oldsite.com` redirect to `http://www.newsite.com/'
- `http://www.oldsite.com/` redirect to `http://www.newsite.com/'

What's not redirecting:

1. The case-insensitive URLs
2. The `/news` link
3. The last two tests (plain urls without a file)

Comment: What is the difference between redirection of `/news` and `/`? `RedirectMatch 302 (?i)/link1 http://www.newsite.com/file.pdf` and the second `Redirect 302 / http://www.newsite.com/` should be enough. Also, `mod_rewrite` is not used here. BTW, `Redirect` works redirecting to the corresponding 'sub-URL', so any `/url` will be redirected to the corresponding `/url` on a new site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple

```
# redirects exact case-insensitive /link1 to a single file 
# if you want to redirect URL starting with /link1... to a file, remove $
RedirectMatch 302 (?i)^/link1$ http://www.newsite.com/file.pdf

# redirects any other url from the old site to the corresponding url on a new one
# so oldsite/some-URL will be transformed into newsite/some-URL
Redirect 302 / http://www.newsite.com/
```

If you want to redirect only from the old server's root to the new server's root, you can use

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ http://www.newsite.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `mod_rewrite` rules for its regex capabilities and other feature like case insensitive handling:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^link1(/.*)?$ http://www.newsite.com/file.pdf [L,NC,R=302]

# Everything Else
RewriteRule (.+) http://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```